# Where does the mysqldump command store the backed up databases?

Tags: mysqldump, ubuntu

I am trying to backup my databases through the terminal in Ubuntu using the `mysqldump` command and it's successful. Where does it place the backed up databases?

I run the command like this:

```sh
$ mysqldump -h localhost -u username - p database_name > back_up_db.sql
```

but have no idea where `back_up_db.sql` is stored.

Answer (score 12):

By default it does it to the working directory at the time the command was made. You need to redirect the output to a file if you need to save it.

The place you put the backup is up to you. Ideally, it should be on a different machine in a different physical location. This is why you usually do a remote MySQL dump over SSH and get the data on a different machine. You just pipe the console output over ssh into a file on a different machine.

Answer (score 12):

It should also be noted that the mysqldump command also has a [switch for a destination file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_result-file).

```
--result-file=file_name, -r file_name
```

Answer (score 7):

Usually you use mysql dump like this

```
mysqldump -h host -u user -ppassword dbname > dumpfile
```

So the output is whatever file you redirect output to. The output file will contain instructions that will rebuild the database from scratch, including the schema, if your run it on a new install like so.

```
mysql -h host -u user -ppassword dbname < dumpfile
```

Here's wiki on [IO redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29)

Answer (score 1):

It will be stored in the path or folder from where you run the mysql command[image]
suppose you run the command from root then it will be stored in the root directory

you can see my backup file skillmappingcleardata.sql in the root directory because I run the mysql command from there